# Compiling the linux Kernel

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel

I am trying to compile the kernel for the Zedboard (having Zync series SoC from Xilinx). And I'm following the following scripts:

```
git clone git://github.com/Xilinx/linux-xlnx
git checkout -b xilinx-v2014.2.01 xilinx-v2014.2.01
wget http://downloads.architechboards.com/deposit/microZed_wilink8.config -O .config
make LOADADDR=0x8000 uImage
make modules
```

So you can see that i have got one .config file from above source. Here are mine doubts:

1. Generally I have seen as standard practice that first `make menuconfig` is called, then `make defconfig`, then `make uImage`, then `make modules`. But in this case `make menuconfig` and `make defconfig` are omitted. So is it right to follow the above scripts if I have already `.config` file from above webpage? Or should I follow the standard steps?
2. Who is going to use `.config` file - `make uImage` command or `make modules` command?
3. So if I changed some parameter in the `.config` file that I have got from above mentioned webpage, then do I need to call any other command before calling the `make uImage` and `make modules` command?

Comment: Note how whenever you make any of the `<something>config` targets, it says something along the lines of "configuration saved to .config" at the end. If you've already got a ready-made config, you obviously don't need to go through the steps of generating one from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct.

1. `make menuconfig`/`make defconfig` will do some magic and as a result generate `.config`. If `.config` file is provided, you skip `make *config` commands.
2. Both `make uImage` and `make modules` requires `.config`. Yes, I have checked this in the top Makefile, you could do this as well.
3. I'm not sure if kernel's build system can detect changes in `.config` file. I would suggest you to rebuild the kernel completely after `make clean`.